# Exception in program to read a file for amounts of different coins and print out total

Tags: java

I am writing a program that reads from a file and prints out the amount of money represented. For example, the text of my input file is

```
3 pennies
2 quarters
1 pennies
23 nickels
4 dimes
```

The program is supposed to calculate the total amount of money and print it out. While the program compiles, I am getting the exception `IllegalFormatConversionException`. I suspect that I have checked for the string (coin name) incorrectly, but I am unsure of how to fix the program. I would appreciate some guidance.
Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;


public class CountCoins {
    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(new FileReader("input.txt"));

        int sum = 0;
        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            int number = input.nextInt();
            String coin = input.next();

            sum += countMoney(number, coin);
        }

        System.out.printf("Total money = $%f \n", sum);

}

        public static double countMoney(int num, String coin) {

            if (coin.equals("pennies")) {
                return num * 0.01;
            }

            else if (coin.equals("nickels")) {
                return num * 0.05;
            }

            else if (coin.equals("dimes")) {
                return num * 0.10;
            }

            else if (coin.equals("quarters")) {
                return num * 0.25;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: your program surely says more than that. Look at the error stack trace it normally indicates the exact line that goes wrong

Comment: the output should be Total money = $2.09

Answer (score 1):

You are using an integer `int sum = 0;` to sum your values while using `$%f`, which is used to format a `float`. Thats the reason you are getting a `IllegalFormatConversionException` here.

I think your intention here is to use floating point values, as indicated by your method `double countMoney` so i suggest you change your `sum` to a `double` as well. Otherwise, you will have a value loss.

```
double sum = 0;
while (input.hasNextLine()) {
    int number = input.nextInt();
    String coin = input.next();
    sum += countMoney(number, coin);
}

System.out.printf("Total money = $%f \n", sum);
```